# Perl User Input

Tags: perl, input

How can I detect Ctrl+D in order to break out of the loop in Perl?

```
while (1){

   $input = <STDIN>;

   print $input; 

   #This is where I would check for CTRL+D
   #last if ($input equals to CTRL+D); EXIT LOOP

   if($input > 0){
    print " is positive\n";
   }

   elsif($input < 0){
    print " is negative\n";
   }

   else { print " is zero\n"; }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
while (defined($input = <STDIN>)) {
    ...
}
```

When the user enters Ctrl-D, `<STDIN>` will return `undef`.

More generally, you can do

```
while (defined($input = <>)) {
    ...
}
```

and your program will read input from any files named in `@ARGV`, or from `<STDIN>` if there are no command-line arguments.